# Sending fcm from PYTHON(flask) but not receiving on android side

Tags: python, android, flask, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

Here are three different ways I try to send data message fcm.

**1. With pyfcm**

```
def send_fcm(fcm_tokens, title=None, body=None, data_message=None):
    push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=app.config['FCM_KEY'])
    try:
        if type(fcm_tokens) is list:
            print(fcm_tokens, data_message)
            result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=fcm_tokens, data_message=data_message)
            print(result, '++++++++++++++', flush=True)
        else:
            print(fcm_tokens, 'single device', data_message)
            result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=fcm_tokens, data_message=data_message)
            print(result, flush=True)
    except errors.InvalidDataError as e:
        print(e, flush=True)
```

**2. With firebase_admin sdk**

```
def send_fcm_with_sdk(tokens, data_message=None):

    if type(tokens) is list:
        message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
            data=data_message,
            tokens=tokens, )
        response = messaging.send_multicast(message)
        print('{0} messages were sent successfully'.format(response.success_count), flush=True)
    else:
        message = messaging.Message(
            data=data_message,
            token=tokens,
        )
        print(message)
        response = messaging.send(message)
        print('Successfully sent message:', response)
```

**3. With rest api**

```
def send_fcm_with_rest(tokens, title=None, body=None, image=None, data_message=None):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'key=xxxxxxxKEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
    if type(tokens) is list:
        payload = {
            "registration_ids": tokens,
            "collapse_key": "type_a",
            "data": data_message

        }
    else:
        payload = {
            "to": tokens,
            "collapse_key": "type_a",
            "data": data_message
        }
    print(json.dumps(payload))
    resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

    print(resp.text.encode('utf8'), flush=True)
    return resp
```

The strange thing is all three of them run correctly and show a success message, with success_id, but none of fcm is received on the android side.

I tried sending from POSTMAN, and from postman, fcm are received on Andriod side.
Can anyone please tell me what is the issue in my code?

Comment: can you post the curl request you're making in POSTMAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the three methods for sending fcm is correct, later we figure out it was the issue from the frontend guy. So anyone can use these three methods if they want to.

Comment: Those frontend guys... can't bring them anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK, however you should use `flask==1.1.2` version as it is the stable release.